# What is this '90s–'00s sf movie with a Guyver-like, Max Steel-like bio suit?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a trailer of this one movie, vague memory of teenagers finding a spaceship wreck or crash. One teenager found this controller/medallion thing which might be shaped like a diamond. This controller/medallion gives the teenager a kind of bio suit (much like Guyver's or Ultraman's) and in turn the teenager protects the earth from invading aliens or some race from another dimension of some sort. I clearly remember it being a space ship and aliens though. This film seems to be directly inspired by *The Guyver* movies and essentially recycled to what is today looks to be like *Max Steel* (2016).

A vague memory I have is that the trailer showed a lot of armored aliens and the protagonist was jump kicking them 1 by 1

I need the title, desperately wanna watch it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I saw the trailer years ago in the 90's. The protagonist is a lone hero at the age range of maybe 17-20 with a bio-suit he got using the controller/medallion. The story and character borrows a lot from Shaider, Guyver, and The Masked Rider Black series.

The said trailer went on air 2 or 3 years after The Guyver movies and I believe it was an american film.

Comment: How early/late in 2016 did you watch this trailer?

Comment: How sure are you that it was a 90's-00's movie?

Comment: Sorry I should have made a more specific post. I saw this trailer in the 90's, never really got to watch the actual film. I remember it was years after The Guyver movies but before The Matrix. I already did my research and that's just it, I haven't found the trailer but it might have been so underwhelming at the time that it didn't warrant any recording in the internet. I'm willing to hope otherwise though.

Comment: It looks like you've done a fair bit of research, which is good, but can you show us what you've found so far? Even negatives will help us :)

Comment: I have posted an answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I found it. It looks ugly, but the forest fight scene and the alien army looks to be the closest to what I have pictured in my head. I remember how I desperately wanted to watch this when I was young, tokusatsus were all the rage back then. Too bad couldn't find the actual film.

title: Power King
protagonist: Armicron
imdb: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296811/plotsummary?ref_=adv_pl
video:

Movie link: https://archive.org/details/ca59_20200329

Answer (score 4):

Look, you *may* have watched the trailer for the *[Power Rangers (2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kIe6UZHSXw)* movie. The only thing is that this is more recent than what you've alluded to.

It features a group of teenagers who:

- Find a spaceship
- Find a 'medallion' control object, buried near the spaceship

  - Medallion is shaped like a gem, similar to a diamond
- *Become* the Power Rangers and therefore have a biosuit
- Eventually fight 'alien' creatures

  - Rita Repulsa's rock minions look like aliens
- Fight to protect earth

**It's morphin' time!**

Comment: It does follow more of the same story but it's not The Power Rangers, he was a lone hero. Continuing my own research might find it in the lesser known parts of the internet. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible you're thinking of the 1997-1998 film, *[Star Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Kid)*?

[image: Star Kid soundtrack cover]

> Spencer Griffith (Joseph Mazzello) is a shy seventh grader and 12-year-old boy. He has a crush on a school girl named Michelle (Lauren Eckstrom). Spencer's life changes when a mysterious meteorite crashes into a nearby junkyard. Investigating the site, he finds that the "meteorite" is actually a small rocket carrying a "Cyborsuit.", a prototype exoskeletal-suit with AI (short for Artificial Intelligence) from another galaxy. Spencer then decides to try the suit on and melds with the suit AI, who Spencer calls "Cy". After testing most of the functions and abilities of the suit, he then goes around town doing whatever he wants, such as getting back at a school bully Turbo (Joey Simmrin), rescuing Michelle and her friends from a damaged ferris wheel, and ordering food from a fast-food restaurant drive-thru, along with a few hilarious antics such as trashing his house while getting his head stuck in a refrigerator, figuring out how to eat a hamburger through the suit and wanting to get out of the suit to pee when Cy wouldn't let him.
>
> During this time, Earth gets visited by a Broodwarrior (Brian Simpson), a member of an alien race of insectoids waging a war against the creator of the Cyborsuit, Tenris De'Thar and his fellow Trelkins. The Broodwarrior's mission is to capture the Cyborsuit so that his race can analyze it. After his first encounter with the Broodwarrior, Spencer escapes, forces Cy to eject him out of the suit and then abandons Cy telling him that he's afraid that he might not live to see his next birthday if he "engages" the Broodwarrior. Back at home, after Spencer looks over his comic book titled MidKnight Warrior and thinking about what kind of person he wants to be, he goes back out to find Cy only to find out that Cy was captured by the Broodwarrior. Spencer begins searching for Cy accompanied by Turbo, now becoming his friend. As they head to the junkyard, where Cy is about to be taken off-world by the Broodwarrior, they create a plan to distract the Broodwarrior long enough for Spencer to rescue Cy. Spencer gets Cy back and begins battling with the Broodwarrior.

....

> With the Broodwarrior now destroyed, they return to Cy but it appears they were too late to save him. Just when Spencer begins to lose hope, Cy's creator Tenris De'Thar and Trelkin soldiers appear from a giant UFO and quickly repair him, bringing him back to life. After Cy and Spencer say goodbye to one another, one of the aliens gives Spencer a badge for his bravery and courage before their departure back to their home-world. The next day at school, a now confident Spencer, with encouragement from his new friend Turbo, starts up a conversation with Michelle.

### Trailer

Comment: No it's not, I have watched the Star Kid. The trailer showed alot of armored aliens and the protagonist was jump kicking them 1 by 1(vague memory). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for it as well…closet I found was ‘The Guyver’

https://m.imdb.com/video/vi1660092697/?playlistId=tt0101988&ref_=vp_rv_ap_0

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question mentions *The Guyver*, so logically that's not it.

Comment: The OP already [answered their own question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/162442/122024), identifying the movie they were looking for as _[Power King](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296811/?ref_=ttpl_ov)_ (1995). If that's not the movie you're looking for, you're presumably looking for something different. You might want to post your own story-ID question, which you can do by clicking on the '[Ask Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)' button at the top of the page.